# tabbar is comming along with keyboard in android even after adding <activity android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" >.any other way

Tags: keyboard, maui, tabbar

tab bar is getting while we are clicking on keyboard instead it should hide beyond the keyboard.

I tried it but not working in android maui.so please provide any alternate methods for implementing in .net Maui android. tabbar hiding

Comment: You mean you want this [effect](https://imgur.com/a/SPocrlX)?

Comment: Hi @android-developer, thanks for your question. However I struggle to understand your question. I recommend you add some more context and details to the question. That way you have a higher chance that someone will answer.